# SQL script not executing in bash

Tags: oracle, bash, unix

I am running an SQL script from bash. One of the scripts seems to be running fine, but the other script fails. Can you please advise what might be the cause for the same?

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlplus -S user/password@database << EOF
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo off 
set heading off
@MyScript1
@MyScript2
exit;
EOF
```

Error:
`SP2-0310: unable to open file "MyScript2.sql"`

In Unix the access level for both is:

```
 -rwxrwxrwx  MyScript1.sql
 -rwxrwxrwx  MyScript2.sql
```

The error does give an indication that it is not able to access the file `MyScript2.sql`. But what I am curious about is how come it can access `MyScript1.sql` which is present in the same folder, but not `MyScript2.sql`?

Also if I run the file just in unix (using SQL*Plus) from the folder where the files are present it works fine. But if I run the same from a different folder it doesn't. Below example will explain it better

`/Folder/having/the/files`

both  `MyScript1.sql` and `MyScript2.sql`  run fine

`/Some/random/folder`

`MyScript1.sql` runs fine , but `MyScript2.sql` errors out

Comment: Do commands from `MyScript1` actually get executed? What happens if you comment out the `@MyScript1` line?

Comment: yes `MyScript1` does get execute . if I comment out `@MyScript1`, I  only get the error `SP2-0310: unable to open file "MyScript2.sql"`

Comment: My best bet so far is a typo in the name, something like `MyScript2.sql` vs `Myscript2.sql`. Have you tried renaming `MyScript2.sql` somehow differently?

Comment: Mate , It is definitely not a typo . Can confirm that .

Comment: Try fully qualifying the name of MyScript2 in your shell script, i.e. refer to it as `@/some/dirs/here/MyScript2.sql`.

Comment: @BobJarvis I will try that and it might work. But the question still remains how does MyScript1.sql work without the full path but MyScript2.sql doesn't?

Comment: This sounds pretty weird. I'd try running the script under `strace` and then grep for MyScript2. But before that I'd make sure that the file I use is entirely innocent: `cat MyScript2.sql > innocent.sql && mv MyScript2.sql strange.sql && mv innocent.sql MyScript2.sql`. This copies the contents, but not any special attributes, and creates a name from scratch.

Comment: @9000 mate did as suggested. The folder now has `strange.sql` and `MyScript2.sql`. But when I try to run `strange` or `MyScript2` i'm still getting the error `SP2-0310: unable to open file`

Comment: Do you have [`$SQLPATH`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#sthref66) set, and if so do you have a file called `MyScript1.sql`, or a link to your real file with that name, in that directory? If you aren't running the script in the same directory as your files then you will need to give the full path (or set `$SQLPATH` in your acript, which might have side effcts (skipping `login.sql`, so just using the full path ought to work better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

> if I run the file just in unix (using SQL*Plus) from the folder where the
>   files are present it works fine. But if I run the same from a
>   different folder it doesn't.

If you run the bash script from a different folder to where you have the SQL files, how do you expect SQL*Plus to know where to find those? The question becomes not 'why can't it see `MyScript2.sql`, but why it *can* see `MyScript1.sql`. The obvious answer is that it can't, or at least can't see the version of the file you think it's seeing.

From the [SQL*Plus documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#sthref67):

> SQL*Plus searches for SQL scripts, including login.sql, in the current
>   directory and then in the directories specified by SQLPATH, and in the
>   subdirectories of SQLPATH directories.

So if you haven't given the full path to the SQL file, it will search in the current working  directory - where you are sitting when you execute the bash script, not the directory the bash script is in, i.e. what `pwd` shows - and the in `$SQLPATH` if it is set.

That suggests you have a copy of `MyScript1.sql` in one of those places, or possibly a soft link to your real file. If I had to guess, I'd speculate that you originally wrote `MyScript.sql` the same directory as the script, then copied it to another directory before writing `MyScript2.sql`. In any case, the `MyScript1.sql` you're running might be out of date, or is likely to become so in the future.

The short answer is to give the full path to the SQL files, either as part of the `@` command, or by changing to that directory in the bash script before launching SQL*Plus.